# how can i achieve order by before group by when selecting from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying retrieve data from mysql tables using php. my code is like this:

```
$sql="SELECT t.tagname, v.videotitle, v.videolength ,f.frametime, f.videoloc FROM video v, tag t, frame f, framename fn WHERE t.tagid = fn.tagid and fn.frameid=f.frameid and v.videoloc=f.videoloc AND tagname LIKE '".$value."' group by fn.section";
```

Tagname Videotitle  Videolength Frametime
pc----------test------- 00:00:03-----1/0.17s
pc----------test--------00:00:03-----6/1.07s

f.frametime column is not smallest number i want because my database order is like this. then i change to:

```
$sql="SELECT t.tagname, v.videotitle, v.videolength ,f.frametime, f.videoloc FROM video v, tag t, frame f, framename fn WHERE t.tagid = fn.tagid and fn.frameid=f.frameid and v.videoloc=f.videoloc AND tagname LIKE '".$value."' order by f.frametime";
```

Tagname Videotitle  Videolength Frametime
pc-----------test--------00:00:03--------1/0.17s
pc-----------test--------00:00:03--------2/0.35s
pc-----------test--------00:00:03--------3/0.53s
pc-----------test--------00:00:03--------5/0.89s
pc-----------test--------00:00:03--------6/1.07s

**BTW**, frame 1,2,3 have same section id 1 and frame 5,6 have section id 2.
this give me correct order but they are not grouped together. my problem will be solved if i can order by f.framename first followed by group by fn.section. however syntax is not correct.

what i want to achieve is this:

Tagname Videotitle  Videolength Frametime
pc----------test------- 00:00:03-----1/0.17s
pc----------test--------00:00:03-----5/0.89s

any idea?
appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
Select * From (
SELECT t.tagname, v.videotitle, v.videolength 
,f.frametime, f.videoloc 
FROM video v, tag t, 
frame f, framename fn 
WHERE t.tagid = fn.tagid and fn.frameid=f.frameid 
and v.videoloc=f.videoloc 
AND tagname LIKE '".$value."' order by f.frametime
) new_table
group by new_table.section
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i changed your code a little bit and it works. i tried your code in phpmyadmin and it says #1054 - Unknown column 'f.framename' in 'order clause', see details in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

based on Rahautos' answer i solve it.
his answer gives me #1054 - Unknown column 'f.framename' in 'order clause'  because i didn't select 'section' column in original statement.
so i added it in:

```
Select tagname, videotitle, videolength, frametime, videoloc From ( SELECT t.tagname, v.videotitle, v.videolength ,f.frametime, f.videoloc, fn.section FROM video v, tag t, frame f, framename fn WHERE t.tagid = fn.tagid and fn.frameid=f.frameid and v.videoloc=f.videoloc AND tagname LIKE '".$value."' order by f.frametime) new_table group by new_table.section
```

this gives me exactly what i want even though data in mysql table is not in order.